# Excel creating autofilling form

Tags: forms, excel, vlookup, vba

I'm trying to create a form which contains two entries:
-folder number
-list of toms which are in folders
This is for archiving purpose. Form is divided on 4 section which will be printed on labels for archive boxes. 
Folders are numbered from 1 to 1500, some of them contain 1 tom of documents, some of them up to 10. For now I'm doing this manualy by just copying from the table which looks like this:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5dLx.jpg)

Only thing I need in form is TOM NUMBER from this table

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygZRq.jpg)

I was trying to use VLOOKUP but it only returns first row which has searched folder number.
So bascially I want a function which will take folder number from label form and find all toms which are assigned to and write it below. first 3 digits in folder number aren't important, only last 4 digits are considered most important variable

Comment: can you tell me if "Toms" are files? if so, where are they located?

Comment: no, they are just entries on archive list in our internal standard name:

OPO A1 W  ---------- DL XXX 

Folder numbers are written as

1XX B20 ZE 122011 YYYY

Comment: thank you i'm working on a solution. it may take a few.

Comment: @JamTay317 thank you, by the time, found this: {=INDEX($A$2:$C$7,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$7=$A$9,ROW($A$2:$A$7)),ROW(1:1))-1,3)} but can't make it work for my table

Comment: I have created a form that will do all of this for you. I am going to post steps here and if you would like msg me and ill send you the copy.

Comment: @JamTay317 I would be greatful

Comment: I added a link to download it from dropbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately vlookup will not work, you are going to have to use an array folder. I am making an assumption that you will have a table that is called [Folders]
and I am going to create a form form with some vba on how to do this.
1. Create a Table  by selecting the folder dataset and push ctl+T. [image: Folder Table]

2. Alt + F11 to enter Visual basic editor
3. At the top choose insert ==> UserForm
4. Push F4 and in the properties window name your form FileFinder
5. Your toolbox maynot appear if it doesn't choose view => toolbox to open
6. drag 2 labels, 2 listboxes, and 2 buttons, you can format it however you like.
   [image]
   7.Create a new Module same as adding userform only choose module
7. Copy paste this code

   `Public Function CreateWorksheet(Optional name As String = "") As Worksheet
       Dim ws As Worksheet
       Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
       If name <> "" Then ws.name = name
       Set Create = ws
   End Function
   Public Function LastRow() As Integer 'gets last row from column A
       LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   End Function
   Public Function DistintFolders() As String()
       Dim list() As String
       Dim counter As Integer
       For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
           If Not IsInList(list, cell.Value, counter) Then
               counter = counter + 1
               ReDim Preserve list(1 To counter)
               list(counter) = cell.Value
           End If
       Next cell
       DistintFolders = list
   End Function
   Public Function TomNumberByFolder(folderName As Variant) As String()
       Dim list() As String
       Dim counter As Integer
       Dim rowNumber As Integer
       For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
           rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
           If IsCorrectFolder(folderName, rowNumber) Then
               counter = counter + 1
               ReDim Preserve list(1 To counter)
               list(counter) = cell.Value
           End If
       Next cell
       TomNumberByFolder = list
   End Function
   Public Function IsInList(ByRef list() As String, compare As String, count As Integer) As Boolean
   Dim l As Variant
       If compare = "" Then
           IsInList = True
           Exit Function
       End If
       If count = 0 Then
           IsInList = False
           Exit Function
       End If
       For Each l In list
           If l = compare Then
               IsInList = True
               Exit Function
           End If
       Next l
       IsInList = False
   End Function
   Public Function IsCorrectFolder(folderName As Variant, rowNumber As Integer) As Boolean
       IsCorrectFolder = (ActiveSheet.Range("E" & rowNumber).Value = folderName)
   End Function`
8. double click your form and paste this code

`

```
    Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub btnCreate_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    If lstTom.ListCount = 0 Then
        MessageBox "Please select a folder"
    End If
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Tom Number"

    ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(Me.lstTom.ListCount, 1) = Me.lstTom.list
End Sub

Private Sub lstFolder_Click()
     Dim folder As String
     If ActiveSheet.name <> "Data" Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate 'please name this whatever your datasheet is called
     For i = 0 To lstFolder.ListCount - 1
        If lstFolder.Selected(i) Then
            Me.lstTom.Clear

        For Each s In TomNumberByFolder(lstFolder.list(i))
                With lstTom
                    .AddItem s
                End With
            Next s
        End If
     Next i
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

   For Each s In DistintFolders
        With lstFolder
            .AddItem s
        End With
    Next s
End Sub
```

`

please note that you may have to change sheet names if you would like I will send you this.

[Download Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhqewapl6moa0of/SearchForm.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you very much, Now I found another problem with my form, maybe you could help me with it either

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I will add it in question

Comment: that is a separate question, you should post it as a separate question